# Entity Framework Database First suddenly started showing "The symbol has already been defined"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I deleted and recreated an Entity Framework model from the database (edmx model). All settings were left to default.

Suddenly I'm getting over 80 error messages:

> Error     Error 10001: The symbol 'Entities' has already been
> defined.  projectname C:\Projects\projectname\application\projectname\projectname\BusinessLogic\Orm\Entities.edmx 1494
>
> Error     Error 10001: The symbol 'Entities.C__MigrationHistory' has
> already been
> defined.  projectname C:\Projects\projectname\application\projectname\projectname\BusinessLogic\Orm\Entities.edmx 1495
>
> Error     Error 10001: The symbol 'Entities.FK_ArticleRevisions_Articles'
> has already been
> defined.  projectname C:\Projects\projectname\application\projectname\projectname\BusinessLogic\Orm\Entities.edmx 1513
>
> Error     Error 10001: The symbol
> 'Entities.FK_ArticleRevisions_Articles.Articles' has already been
> defined.  projectname C:\Projects\projectname\application\projectname\projectname\BusinessLogic\Orm\Entities.edmx 1514

... and so on for each foreign key relation I have.

I do this process fairly regularly for multiple different projects and this has never happened. I tried to redo the process, clear .NET cache files, clear the bin and obj folders for the project, restart VS, restart PC. Nothing helped.

I noticed that the edmx file indeed contains duplicate association definitions.

Answer (score 1):

After a few days the problem disappeared by itself. Probably not a helpful answer. :)